# Regex PHP only gets the first match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have an string which looks like:

> aaaaaaaa'bbbbbbbb?'cccccccccccc'ddddddddd'

I would like to get all the matches separate by `'` but not the ones escaped with `?'`

I managed to do it by using this expression:

```
(.*?)[^\\?]'
```

And I tested it on [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) and seems to work properly.

When trying to apply it to my PHP code by using [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/preg_match) I only get the first match.

This is my code:

```
preg_match ("/(.*?)[^\\?]'/i", $content, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

And the result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
    [1] => aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
)
```

I'm expecting to get `bbbbbbbb?'cccccccccccc'` and `ddddddddd'` as well.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What kind of string is this? Do you have a grammar for it? With only a single example, you are going to get answers tailored to your example and may not work in more general cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this `negative lookbehind` regex in `preg_match_all`:

```
$s = "aaaaaaaa'bbbbbbbb?'cccccccccccc'ddddddddd'";
if (preg_match_all("/(.*?)(?<!\?)'/", $s , $m ))
    print_r($m[1]);
```

OR using `preg_split`:

```
$arr = preg_split("/(?<!\?)'/", $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [0] => aaaaaaaa
    [1] => bbbbbbbb?'cccccccccccc
    [2] => ddddddddd
)
```

Comment: Thanks,works great but... why have you used `(?<!\?)'/` instead of what i had?

Comment: Lookbehind is better here since we don't match character before `'` we just take a peek. What if there is no character before like `''`

Comment: btw you have a minor mistake also `[^\\?]` negates backslash also but `[^?]` will be correct. Though still prefer lookbehind than matching.

Answer (score 1):

use [preg_match_all()](https://www.php.net/preg_match_all) to get all matches instead of one

```
$content = "aaaaaaaa'bbbbbbbb?'cccccccccccc'ddddddddd'";
preg_match_all("/(.*?)[^\\?]'/i", $content, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

result

```
Array ( 
        [0] =>
                Array ( 
                        [0] => aaaaaaaa' 
                        [1] => bbbbbbbb?'cccccccccccc' 
                        [2] => ddddddddd' 
                        ) 
        [1] => 
                Array ( 
                        [0] => aaaaaaa 
                        [1] => bbbbbbbb?'ccccccccccc 
                        [2] => dddddddd 
                        ) 
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simply You can try this**

```
$s = "aaaaaaaa'bbbbbbbb?'cccccccccccc'ddddddddd'";
$arr = preg_split("/[^?]'/", $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

**Out Put Array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => aaaaaaa
    [1] => bbbbbbbb?'ccccccccccc
    [2] => dddddddd
)
```